# Sketch3: how do you draw a fan shape?

Tags: sketch-app

I'd like to have a circle divided into 4 fans, each of them is identical, if I draw the fan using edit tool, it is quite hard to get a perfect circle when four fans are combined.

Is there any trick to do this?

What I am trying to achieve is drawing a slice of a pie chart.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to do it:

- Draw a circle and some rectangles.
- Snap the rectangles to the center of the circle.
- Drag out points as needed.
- Select the circle.
- Choose `Use As Mask` from the `Layer` menu.
- The rectangles should now be masked by the circle.

[image: Sketch pie chart]

Comment: This is near the solution, but I want only one slice of the pie chart

Comment: I got it, I use a triangle and a circle and choose the union area of them

Comment: That will work, but depending on how you’re compositing things (and if there’s many items), you might end up with some bad edges due to the way antialiasing is composited.

Answer (score 1):

A little tedious but crips with Gradient tool:

1. Draw a circle
2. Apply Angular Gradient Fill (there will be two colors selected by default)
3. Double click in the color strip to add additional colors
4. Move the gradient points to the values needed for a crisp edge

http://www.sketchtips.info/articles/how-to-make-a-pie[image: Sketch Pie Chart With Angular Gradient Tool]